# how to display the value stored in array by using for loop in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

*LOGIC:*

- 5 image in a array

example:

```
apple.png,mango.png,bird.png,sun.png,moon.png
```

I need to use `arc4random` in this array, so I got index as 1, so value got mango.png

in other array I stored

```
number = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"4",@"2",@"9",@"1",@"8",@"7",@"5",@"3",@"6",@"10", nil];
```

and used `arc4random` and i got the output as index:2 value as:9

then i need to print 9 times image of mango in image view.

please help how to code this using objective-c

Comment: Where do you want to display them?

Comment: i need to display in  output by using nslog

Comment: means you need to display image 3 times in nslog ?

Comment: What do you want to log with NSLog? The `UIImage` object description?

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@",someVariablecontainingaUIImageReference)` ?

Comment: the image stored is   "<UIImage: 0x60800008edd0>, {640, 480}",
    "<UIImage: 0x60800008ef60>, {1920, 1200}",
    "<UIImage: 0x60800008efb0>, {1024, 768}",
    "<UIImage: 0x60800008f410>, {640, 480}",
    "<UIImage: 0x60000008eec0>, {300, 300}",
    "<UIImage: 0x60000008ef60>, {640, 480}",
    "<UIImage: 0x60000008f0a0>, {1920, 1200}",
    "<UIImage: 0x60000008f140>, {1024, 768}",
    "<UIImage: 0x60000008f1e0>, {640, 480}",
    "<UIImage: 0x60000008f280>, {300, 300}"

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you have to show random Image in `ImageView` on the basis of random number.

Have a look below code,

```
images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navarre-Family-Eye-Care-Navarre-Florida-Optometrist-Santa-Christmas-Toy-Safety.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpaper-jesus-9413550-1024-768.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"luxury-christmas-napkins-father-christmas-1635-p.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navarre-Family-Eye-Care-Navarre-Florida-Optometrist-Santa-Christmas-Toy-Safety.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpaper-jesus-9413550-1024-768.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"luxury-christmas-napkins-father-christmas-1635-p.jpg"], nil];

int randomIndex=arc4random() % images.count;
UIImage *selectedImage = [images objectAtIndex:randomIndex]; //random selected image

number = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10", nil];
int randomNumber = arc4random() % number.count; //random selected number

NSInteger indexValue = [number indexOfObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",randomNumber]]; // get index number of your random number

for (int i = 0; i <indexValue ; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%@", selectedImage);
    yourImageView.Image = selectedImage;
}
```

Comment: i got the answer but , in number array have 10 number and random number =2

Comment: Yes, your number arrays has 10 numbers and random number 2 then for loop will run 2 times and image will show two time. Do want to know else?

Comment: i need the display the value stored in the index not the random number

Comment: I didn't get your question. I really don't understand which index you are talking about. Please explain more

Comment: i got randomIndex =1 then selectedImage =Christmas-Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg so i used to display that image, such way i need the answer as random number=2 then selectednumber=3 .how to do

Comment: ok, then do randomNumber-1. So that if RandomNumber comes 4 then index no will be 3. So loop will run till randomNumber-1. See my edit

Comment: i need the answer as now update logic mentioned above

Comment: As per your comment, I have updated my answer. Only change is randomNumber-1 in for loop

Comment: i need random number =5 and its index value stored in the array is 7 and i need to display as image 7 times but when i used random number-1 then it display 4 times the image.

Comment: Have you got your answer @jesteena?

Answer (score 0):

Important thing is where do you want to display the image.

From the above snippet what I can understand is v(NSArray) is assigned with UIImage. 
If you want to use v as NSArray then add UIImage as an object to the Array, then you will be able to access image using index.

```
NSArray *v=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:randomIndex], nil];
```

then you can NSLog the image object with below code

```
for (int i= 0 ; i<ran; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[v objectAtIndex:0]);
   _cardsImageView.image = [v objectAtIndex:0]
}
```

Comment: i need display in imageview.

Comment: you need to create UIImageview to display the content. If Imageview is setup then you can display using below code
UIImage 
        _cardsImageView.image = [v objectAtIndex:0];

Answer (score 0):

you have to show number of times images in NSLog as per the random number comes. so just add the following code at the end of your existing code.

```
int count = [[number objectAtIndex:ran] intValue];
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",v);
    }
```

Comment: @jesteena just add this 5 line code of your existing code (at the end) and check it